# How do I 'better' my paths to lsp server binaries whilst using nvim-lsp-install?

Tags: path, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

At the moment, every time I install a new LPS server using [nvim-lsp-installer](https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer), I add an entry to my `.zshenv`, so that the bin folder of the server is available to `$PATH`:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/python/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

The [nvim-lsp-installer documentation](https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer/blob/main/doc/nvim-lsp-installer.txt) recommends setting up the path with the `cmd` option in each individual LSP configuration. The thing is that I have never seen that in any of my favorite dotfiles from my favorite fellow neovimers that use [lsp-config](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig).
Am I missing something? Is there a way to automate the process? Is there a way to add the bin folders to `$PATH` during server installation? Or am I doing it the "normal" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to modify your `PATH` manually when using nvim-lsp-installer. The minimal setup recommends the following (there's more in the [README](https://github.com/williamboman/nvim-lsp-installer#setup)):

```
local lsp_installer = require("nvim-lsp-installer")

lsp_installer.on_server_ready(function (server)
   server:setup {}
end)
```

By setting up the server via the above interface, nvim-lsp-installer will be able to modify the settings with the necessary properties before passing it onwards to lspconfig.

*If* you'd like to be able to run the language server executables from a shell, you'd probably be better off installing them manually into a location on your `PATH` rather than going through nvim-lsp-installer.